# Не изменяется цвет chip

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Всем привет!

Столкнулась со следующей проблемой:
Программно устанавливаю `binding.chip.isSelected = true`, но после выбора другого `chip2` цвет `chip` не изменяется. При этом установлен выбор только одного `chip` в группе

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем может быть связана данная проблема?

`fragment_add_event.xml`

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:singleSelection="true">

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chip"
                    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Chip.Suggestion.Elevated"
                    app:chipIconVisible="true"
                    app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_2"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                    android:id="@+id/chip2"
                    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Chip.Suggestion.Elevated"
                    app:chipIconVisible="true"
                    app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_1"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

`AddEventFragment.kt`

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentAddEventBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        tracker?.let {
            binding.note.setText(it.note)
            if(it.mood_id == 1){
                binding.chip.isSelected = true
            }
            else {
                binding.chip2.isSelected = true
            }
        } ?: kotlin.run {

        }
        ...
```

[image: Пример]

Спасибо!

Comment: Выбирая элементы напрямую, вы возможно нарушаете логику работы группы. Она и не знала, что что-то было выбрано. Пользуйтесь методами группы https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipGroup#check(int)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja check помог решить проблему, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решена использованием chipGroup.check(chipId)